# Only show partial area of QT QMediaPlayer video (crop)

Tags: qt, pyqt

I want to show only a partial area of a playing `QMediaPlayer` video, for example if its a 1280x720 video I might only want to show some area in the middle from `QPoint(300,300)` with a size of `QSize(200,200)`.

I already tried using `QGraphicsVideoItem()` with setOffset and applying `QTransform.translate`, however `setOffset` seems to do nothing and with transforms `rotate` works but `translate` doesn't seem to do anything.

How could I do this?

Comment: can you attach the core code？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay turns out you can basically crop anything by just putting it inside a parent QWidget, and setting that widgets geometry.

By setting x and y negative you can push the top left corner outside the rendered area, and by setting width and height you can set how much is shown, basically allowing you to show any specific section of the QWidgets contents.

```
qw = QWidget()
qw.setParent(self)
qw.setGeometry(-150,-150,500,500)

videoWidget = QVideoWidget()
videoWidget.setParent(qw)
videoWidget.show()

mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
```

And you can then just nest that QWidget in another one to still be able to place it anywhere on the screen like usual.